# "Unexpected Token <" when trying to run node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

It would appear that in my adaptation of `react-server-example` (https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example) *I cannot seem to use JSX*. I have since made some changes (like replace Browserify with Webpack and so forth) however, after extensive looking around and installing `babel-present-react`, I can't seem to figure out what I am missing in order to run the app.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-server-example",
  "version": "1.1.5",

...

  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.5",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

[image: Errors when trying to run node]

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "jsx-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel",
                query:
                  {
                    presets:['react']
                  }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Comment: You could look into [express-react-views](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views), which uses Babel to render React views on the server, much like any other template engine, such as Jade.

Comment: Can you also share how you've configured babel and how you're using babel to process the file?

Comment: so I have added a .babelrc file but I haven't done anything else with Babel...

Comment: What you may be missing is the use of Babel, as Node won't use Babel itself. You have to either compile the file from JSX to ES/JS before executing it (`babel server.jsx -o server.js; node server.js`) or use Babel's own command for doing both steps in one (`babel-node server.js`).

Comment: when I run that I get `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`

Comment: For that, you'll have to also install [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015). Or, remove `"es2015"` from any `"presets"` collections (`.babelrc`?).

Comment: could you make that an answer? @JonathanLonowski

Comment: Almost 100% positive this is a problem due to a lack of or incorrectly configured `.babelrc` file.

Comment: adding that to the question @rossipedia

Comment: have you installed `babel-preset-react`? It's not listed in your `package.json`

Comment: I believe it is actually

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <Test name="wassuppp" />
    );
  }
```

You seem to be missing an opening `(`for the return.

Comment: I don't believe this will work in Javascript... (But if it works in Node, never mind)

Comment: nice catch but `return <element />;` is valid, so are parenthesis.

Comment: This is not correct. The parentheses are syntactic dressing, but are not required. @JohnDoe is correct.